# Swift 3 Garbage at End

Tags: php, json, swift3, xcode8

I am trying to receive info from my server but I keep getting the error telling me that there is Garbage at the end. It could be that the file being passed from the server has HTTP info as well but I do not know how to get rid of it. Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

//URL to our web service
let URL_SAVE_TEAM = "http://<IP Address>/WebServerTest/api/createteam.php"


//TextFields declarations
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldMember: UITextField!


//Button action method
@IBAction func buttonSave(sender: UIButton) {

    //created NSURL
    let requestURL = NSURL(string: URL_SAVE_TEAM)

    //creating NSMutableURLRequest
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL! as URL)

    //setting the method to post
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    //getting values from text fields
    let teamName=textFieldName.text
    let memberCount = textFieldMember.text

    //creating the post parameter by concatenating the keys and values from text field
    let postParameters = "name="+teamName!+"&member="+memberCount!;

    //adding the parameters to request body
    request.httpBody = postParameters.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);


    //creating a task to send the post request
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil{
            print("error is \(error)")
            return;
        }


        //parsing the response
        do {
            //converting resonse to NSDictionary
            let myJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? NSDictionary

            //parsing the json
            if let parseJSON = myJSON {

                //creating a string
                var msg : String!

                //getting the json response
                msg = parseJSON["message"] as! String?

                //printing the response
                print(msg)

            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

    }
    //executing the task
    task.resume()

}
```

I am unable to see the issue.

Comment: You are supposed to use URLRequest instead of NSMutableURLRequest in Swift 3.  You just need to declare is as var.

Comment: also you should use Swift 3 native Dictionary type, so you should cast the json result to `[String: Any]`

Comment: Another point is that the json top level object should be an array or a dictionary and you need to use JSONSerialization to serialize it before sending the data.

Comment: Changing that does not fix the error

Comment: If you get "Garbage at end." with your code, your server is returning an invalid JSON. Put `print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)!)` before `let myJSON = ...` and see what the response is.

Comment: Okay I have made all changes you have suggested except for your last comment. I don't think that I follow, could you give me an example? (I am new to this whole coding in xcode)

Comment: @JacobBlacksten you need to create a dictionary [String: Any], add those keys and values to it (name & member), and use https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization/1413636-data to get the json data from the dictionary.

Comment: If you still have problem just update your question with your actual code. If you need some reference https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization

Comment: Actually making those changes did work, I am still getting the Garbage error however it is posting to the database